# Is it possible to request the controller without retuning thymleaf model

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

Hello I use Thymealf and want to do a validirung against my database before I subbmitte.
When I call the controller I get the error:

```
Error resolving template [], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

I think the error comes from the fact that I don't returne a modal.
Is there a way to make a request without thymleaf ?

### Controller

```
@GetMapping("/getByKey/{key}")
public KeyValuePair keyExists(@PathVariable("key") String key){
    return ssdbService.getByKey(key);
}
```

or do I understand here something completely wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `@RestController` instead of a `@Controller` if you want to return data.

You can also just annotate your method with `@ResponseBody` if you just want one method to return data instead of the entire controller.

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/getByKey/{key}")
public KeyValuePair keyExists(@PathVariable("key") String key){
    return ssdbService.getByKey(key);
}
```

Comment: I created a new controller with @RestController and it worked 
Thanks